# Call activity method from intent service

Tags: java, android

There are many questions on how to invoke an activity method from a service using a broadcast receiver or an interface. But the examples often differs from my case.

I have an activity that sends a registration request to a server. This server sends it's requested answer via **google cloud messaging (GCM)**. To receive the answer I use a **service**.

**My manifest**:

```
<!-- receiver to handle GCM messages -->
<receiver
   android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
   android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
   <intent-filter>
      <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
      <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
      <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
      <category android:name="com.example.myapp" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

In my activity, I have a switch. If the user checks the switch the registration process starts and I disable the switch, so the user could not change the switch state during the registration process. After a certain time (about 5 Min) the server sends the answer.

Depending on the answer, I want to set the state of the switch (checked or unchecked) and enable the switch again.

My question is now, how can I achieve this behaviour? How can I invoke a method in the activity?

The next problem is that the user probably closes the app because the request needs some time. How can I achieve, that the method will be executed even if the activity was closed?

Regarding the questions, I have read in the forum I would use a **LocalBroadcastReceiver**. Would this receiver work, if the app was closed? Or if it is closed, would it bring the activity to the front (I don't want this)?

Comment: Have you considered using Events?

Comment: no. I've never heard of this. I will check it. Thank's

Comment: I think, events are not the solution for this purpose. I.e. I use the `OnCheckedChangeListener` to detect if the user toggled the switch. But I have no idea how to use events to process a GCM message.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some work-arounds to achieve this by re-create your Activity again but this wouldn't be best practice (And also complicated to code).
I would use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), which is a simple to use data file that you can read from anywhere inside your app (e.g your `receiver` or your `activity`).
 **Inside the Receiver -**

```
// PREFS_FILE_NAME - a static String variable like: 
public static final String PREFS_FILE_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putBoolean("mySwitchOn", true);
 editor.commit();
```

**Inside the Activity -**

```
public static final String PREFS_FILE_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);    
  Boolean mSwitchOn = prefs.getBoolean("mySwitchOn", true);//"True is the default value if no value was found.
  //Do what you need with mSwitchOn
}
```

Comment: I already use SharedPreferences to save the information received in my IntentService. But imagine the case, I open the activity, toggle the switch and the registration process begins. But when I only put something into my SharedPreferences-file, the activity doesn't  notice it until I open the activity again.

Comment: If you need to notify you activity when it's alive you can use localBroadcastManager (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) or Application level singleton (http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way i can think for your problem is to use **[LocalBroadcastManger](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)**.
In my current project, there is beacon impl... Whenever i receive signal from beacon in background service, I broadcast intent to activity.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<service
      android:exported="true"
      android:name="com.yourpackage.ServiceName"/>
```

**In your service**

```
 Intent i = new Intent();
 i.setAction(BeaconHelper.ACTION_BEACON_TRIGGER);
 i.putExtra("data", "my_data");
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(i)
```

**In your activity's `onCreate()` or `onResume()`**

```
registerReceiver(mReceiver,new IntentFilter(BeaconHelper.ACTION_BEACON_TRIGGER));
```

**MyReceiver.java**

```
 public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    MyReceiver() {
       
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive() called with: context = [" + context + "], intent = [" + intent + "]");

        try {
            switch (intent.getAction()){
                case BeaconHelper.ACTION_BEACON_TRIGGER:
                        //here is my beacon impl
                   break;

                default:
                    break;

            }
        } catch (JSONException | NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    
}
```

> LocalBroadcastManager only work if your activity and service in same process. If you had put **process** as `<service process=":myprocess"/>` inside **manifest**, it won't probably work.
>
> Make sure you **unregister** after activity got destroyed . :-) .